# Is it possible to visit one of the websites that are sharing a same IP by IP address?

Tags: ip, webmin, virtualmin

I hosted my several websites on Linode, they are all sharing a same IP address.
I use webmin/virtualmin to manage my server and websites. Is it possible to visit one of the websites by IP address?
Currently if I visit the IP, what shows in the browser is just an apache2 default page: http://45.79.146.98/. I think this also points to some folder on my server, but I don't know where it is.

P.S. If I can visit my websites by http://45.79.146.98/something, it is also acceptable. But I don't know where to start doing this.

Comment: I'd say that the first VHost in your apache config is the one showing when no FQDN is defined. Try placing the site you wish at the top of the others, it may work.

Comment: Isn't that [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/106882/how-do-you-have-one-ip-address-and-many-websites) what OP is looking for ?

Comment: Agree, Apache docs:  The asterisks match all addresses, so the main server serves no requests. Due to the fact that the virtual host with ServerName www.example.com is first in the configuration file, it has the highest priority and can be seen as the default or primary server. That means that if a request is received that does not match one of the specified ServerName directives, it will be served by this first <VirtualHost>.  @Alex should make this an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

*Making my comment an answer thanks to docu provided by @marctxk*

The first VHost in your apache config is the one showing when no FQDN is defined. Try placing the site you wish at the top of the others and that's the one being shown when just accessing by IP address.

Apache docs:

> The asterisks match all addresses, so the main server
>   serves no requests. Due to the fact that the virtual host with
>   ServerName www.example.com is first in the configuration file, it has
>   the highest priority and can be seen as the default or primary server.
>   That means that if a request is received that does not match one of
>   the specified ServerName directives, it will be served by this first

Comment: so it is not possible to have all of them being able to be visited by IP?

Comment: @shenkwen Why are you so set on visiting them via IP? If having a proper hostname is so much of a problem, then just add the requisite entries to your hosts file.

Comment: my websites have mirror image on a server in China. Everyday that server syncs the files from the linode server, and ppl from China are actually connected to the Chinese server. The person in charge of updating the website was in the U.S., now that she went back to China, she had trouble updating the website, because what she actually connects to is the Chinese server. So I think if she can visit the website by IP, then she can update the website as usual.

Comment: So do what EEAA advises, and reconfigure her hosts file to have the linode server (if she can connect to it, given the Great Firewall).  And in future, ask the question you actually want to know the answer to (see also [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Totally agree with @EEAA. It is not worth reinventing the wheel (backwards in this case)

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual hosts configuration file, it should be possible to define the `Servername` as your ip address.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost 45.79.146.98:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName 45.79.146.98
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

From the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername)

Syntax: `ServerName [scheme://]domain-name|ip-address[:port]`

Answer (score -1):

Opening that ip address in browser it tells that this file is located at `/var/www/html/index.html`

Edit. As OP owns server, then yes. You can modify that vhost and apache config too. I thinked that linode is doing virtual hosting. But it is doing virtual server hosting. So then op has full control of server. You must modify default config in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory.

In that configuration file change path from `/var/www/html/` to your sites path.

Comment: Why not? How do you think that the OP would not have access to this?