# How do you have multiple websites on one ip address with no dns(raw ip address)?

Tags: ip, hosting, web-hosting, multiple-instances

I have two private websites that are running on different devices, that I want to use but aren't using a DNS, so the web pages that I am using are on the same Ip-Address.  How can I get the contents of device b's webpage w/out contacting device A and vice versa.  They are both port forwarded to Port 80.

I know this might be marked as duplicate from this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/106882/how-do-you-have-one-ip-address-and-many-websites).  The thing that is different is that I do not have a Domain Name compared to the other post.

Comment: When you can't do name based virtual hosting (when you don't have a domain/DNS and don't want to add entries to a local [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on the client and ip-based virtual hosting is not possible you can run sites on different ports and clients will need to use URL's like `http://ip-address:portnumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both devices would have to serve their pages from a different context.

E.g.:

x.x.x.x/devicea/index.html

x.x.x.x/deviceb/index.html

But even then, I don't know how you would be able to do the port forwarding.

So to do it, you would need to port forward to a front-end proxy (Apache, Nginx, HAProxy, etc) which would know how to route to the respective backends based on the URL context (/devicea, /deviceb).

In Apache, it's done with ProxyPass directive.

Comment: This is possible, the port forwarding, but I have one last question.  Can you use a different port for HTML?

Comment: Sure you can run your web server on whatever port you want. HTML is a markup language, not a server, so it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sry I meant apache, mixed it up XD

Answer (score 0):

Get a domain name and DNS. This enables name based virtual hosting, easy TLS certs, changing the IP address in the future, and human readable names. Use subdomains if you only want to get one, so  `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`. Both names can go to a proxy or load balancer to forward onto the web servers.

The one IP address problem goes away when you implement IPv6. Set static addresses like `2001:db8:2498:4479::a` and `2001:db8:2498:4479::b`, both listening on port 80.